# Referencing resource inside usercontrol not working

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a Wpf Application with the following structure

MainSolution -> Views (folder) -> NextGenDG (WPF Project) ->DisplayResources(folder) -> BRUserControlStyles.xaml

Here is  BRUserControlStyles.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NextGenDG.DisplayResources">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary
            Source="/NextGenDG;component/DisplayResources/BRColors.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary
            Source="/NextGenDG;component/DisplayResources/BRFonts.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary
            Source="/NextGenDG;component/DisplayResources/BRButtonStyles.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary
            Source="/NextGenDG;component/DisplayResources/BRCommonControlStyles.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary
            Source="/NextGenDG;component/DisplayResources/BRToggleButtonStyles.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <Style
        x:Key="UserControlDarkBackgroundStyle"
        TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}"
        BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type UserControl}}">
        <Setter
            Property="Margin"
            Value="0" />
        <Setter
            Property="Padding"
            Value="0" />
        <Setter
            Property="Background"
            Value="Red" />
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style
                TargetType="{x:Type Button}"
                BasedOn="{StaticResource ButtonLightTextGradientDarkBackgroundStyle}" />
            <Style
                TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}"
                BasedOn="{StaticResource TextBlockLightTextStyle}" />
            <Style
                TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}"
                BasedOn="{StaticResource ToggleButtonLightTextGradientDarkBackgroundStyle}" />
            <Style
                TargetType="{x:Type Separator}"
                BasedOn="{StaticResource SeparatorDarkLineStyle}" />
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Now I am trying to use the style inside a UserControl that is inside a folder called UserControls as follows. This UserControl is being called in the MainWindow

```
<UserControl x:Class="NextGenDG.UserControls.NextGenHeaderCartridgeStatusUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NextGenDG.UserControls"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
            Style="{DynamicResource UserControlDarkBackgroundStyle}"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
<TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
            Text="{Binding Text}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Problem is if I say StaticResource UserControlDarkBackgroundStyle it complains saying the resource is not found. So when I use DynamicResource UserControlDarkBackgroundStyle it dosen't apply the style. Please help. At a glace is my ResourceDictionary path correct?

Comment: In the designer, or the runtime?  The WPF designer is still a bit wonky and is apt to report errors that aren't exhibited at runtime. If it is design time, one thing you can try is close your solution, nuke all bin and obj folders underneath it, reopen and recompile.

Comment: It happens during the run time. I don't even open my designer. But let me try to clear the bin and obj folders.